# Column 'post_id' cannot be null

Tags: python, django, rest

Column 'post_id' cannot be null

I don't know why I can't bring post_id. If you try to add a comment, you might not be able to bring post_id. I can't solve it. Please help me.

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

serializers.py

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    post = PostSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = (
            'user',
            'post',
            'id',
            'content',
        )
        read_only_fields = ('created_at',)
```

views.py

```
# api/views.py


class CommentView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with below code.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

After replacing the code do the migration and try again

Comment: This doesn't really solve his problem as none of the created comments will be linked to a Post with this fix.

Answer (score 0):

The Comment model has a foreignkey relationship with the Post model. Therefore, if you create a new comment, a value for Post (post_id) must be set. You can either do this in your serializer or in your perform_create method in the viewset.

*In the following example I assume the field with `post id` as value has name `post`. And I did not add validation for the Post to be retrieved.*

Example:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    post = PostSerializer(read_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance = super().create(validated_data)
        instance.post = Post.objects.get(id=self.initial_data['post'])
        instance.save()

        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = (
        'user',
        'post',
        'id',
        'content',
        )
        read_only_fields = ('created_at',)
```